# How to add some text to selected text and reselect it again in visual mode?

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I'm using [QuickRun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun) to execute `php` files or part of `php` code by selecting it in `Visual Mode`.
I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <leader>r :QuickRun<CR>
vnoremap <leader>r :QuickRun<CR>
inoremap <leader>rr <Esc>:QuickRun<CR>
```

It does work great.
But to make it work with selected code in `Visual Mode` I have to add <`?php` before selected text.
For example I have code like:

```
<?php
echo 'first line test';
echo "\n";echo "\n";
echo 'second line test';
echo "\n";echo "\n";
?>
```

I select just this 2 lines:

```
echo 'second line test';
echo "\n";echo "\n";
```

and by pressing `<leader>r` how can I add `<?php` tag before selected lines and then reselect it again to run it by `:QuickRun<CR>`?

Comment: It seems to have some sort of template support. See https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun/blob/master/doc/quickrun.txt#L655, maybe you could use that.

Comment: @muru +1 thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The visual mode range is stored in the [`'<`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27%3c) and `'>` marks. You can set this with [`m<`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#m%3c) and `m>`.
- You can start visual mode with the last selection with [`gv`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#gv)
- You can add lines to the buffer with the [`append()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#append%28%29) function.

Combining this, we could use something like:

```
" The range keyword makes sure we run this function over the
" entire range, instead of over each line in the range
fun! SetRange() range
    " Append the text before the visual selection
    call append(line("'<") - 1, '<?php')

    " Expand visual selection by one line
    execute ':' . line("'<") - 1
    normal m<

    " Reselect
    normal gv

    " Run your function
    QuickRun
endfun

noremap <Leader>r :call SetRange()<CR>
```

If you also want to remove the added line, you could use the normal mode `dd` command. Expanding this function to do that is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: +1 Thank you, thank you, thank you very much. I just had to change QuickRun to execute "'<,'>QuickRun" or I would get an error "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /tmp/vduL2VG/10 on line 5"  Again, thank you very much. It does work great.